# Preprocessor Directive for Repeated Code Blocks (with condition)

Tags: c++, performance, c-preprocessor

Is there any way in C++ to implement a concept like the following pseudo-code?

```
#pragma REPEAT

for (;;)
{
    // code block #1

    #pragma REPEAT_CONDITION(a==1)
        // code
    #end_pragma

    // code block #2
}

#end_pragma
```

Which would get compiled as something like this:

```
if (a == 1)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // code block #1

        // code

        // code block #2
    }
}
else
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // code block #1

        // code block #2
     }
}
```

The goal here being to generate an easily readable piece of performance code by abstracting a condition from the inner loop. Thus not having to manually maintain duplicated code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the preprocessor should be used for conditional compilation and precious little else nowadays. With inline(-suggesting) functions, insanely optimising compilers and enumerations, their most common use cases have been gradually whittled away.

I'm assuming here you don't want to check the condition every time through the loop, even though this cleans up your code considerably:

```
for (;;) {
    // code block #1
    if (a == 1) {
        // code
    }
    // code block #2
}
```

The only reason I could think of you doing this would be for the extra speed of not doing the check multiple times but you may want to actually *check* the impact it has. Unless `// code` is pitifully simple, it will most likely swamp the effect of a single conditional statement.

If you *do* need the separate loops for whatever reason, you may be better off putting those common code blocks into functions and simply calling them with a one-liner:

```
if (a == 1) {
    for (;;) {
        callCodeBlock1();
        // code
        callCodeBlock2();
} else {
    for (;;) {
        callCodeBlock1();
        callCodeBlock2();
    }
}
```

Comment: The most common situation I run into is applying the same image processing technique to different image types - eg. RGB vs monochome vs binary. Generally in this case the 'Conditional Code' block is tiny as you indicated, making the ratio difference between condition and code very small. Also when dealing with images a multi-nested loop is involved. This all sums up to the number of objects that can be processed per second in a real-time environment.

Comment: Your solution above may maintain the performance gain - assuming the functions are inlined - but doesn't (in my opinion) do much for code readability. Also, generally with optimised image processing functions, many variables tend to be involved which makes calling functions a pain.